# How to display inner layout at bottom of the screen

Tags: android

This is my current layout file. I want to display buttons in inner layout bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
        android:hint="Name"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
        android:hint="Delivery Address"

        />




    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789+"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-Mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="#7e7e7e"
        android:textColorHint="#7e7e7e" />



    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        >

        <Button android:id="@+id/moreShoppingButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#ADFF2F"
            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CONFIRM"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#ADFF2F"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a project on Android Studio, and I was working in Linear Layout too. But since I wanted to put buttons at the bottom of the screen I started use **Relative Layout**

I think you also have to do it.

You can change the root Linear Layout into Relative Layout.
The Linear Layout which you have the buttons and want put them at the bottom, you have to set this attribute in this Linear Layout:

android:alignParentBottom = true

You have also to align the childs of Relative Layout. If you don't tell the position of the children of Relative Layout, they tend to be positioned at the top left of the screen.

I think you can do that using other layouts, but this way I wrote above, I put on my application.

Take a look how your code should looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
            android:hint="Name"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_below = "@id/username"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
            android:hint="Delivery Address"

            />




        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mobileNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_below = "@id/address"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:digits="0123456789+"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:maxLength="10"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_below = "@id/mobileNumber"

            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="E-Mail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="#7e7e7e"
            android:textColorHint="#7e7e7e" />



        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButtons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button android:id="@+id/moreShoppingButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CANCEL"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:textColor="#ADFF2F"
                />
            <Button android:id="@+id/placeOrderButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CONFIRM"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:textColor="#ADFF2F"
                />

        </LinearLayout>



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a RelativeLayout. All you need to do is add an empty `View` or `Space` that takes up the remaining space, above the items you want at the bottom. To do that, add a Space with layout_height=0, layout_width = math_parent, and layout_weight=1.